# Mapbox GL - Data driven styling for text-offset

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I need to calculate the value of the `text-offset` layout property in a Mapbox GL layer. The calculation involves `sin` and `cos` calculations, but I cannot figure out the expression syntax as the `text-offset` property requires an array of 2 values.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
"text-offset": [
    ["sin", 5], // x offset, hard-coded example
    ["cos", 10] // y offset, hard-coded example
]
// wanted result: [-0.9589242746631385, -0.8390715290764524]
```

This produces the error `number expected, array found` as it violates the rule that the expression array must start with a string defining the type of the expression.

Wrapping the arrays in a `literal` doesn't help either:

```
"text-offset": [
    "literal", [
        ["sin", 5],
        ["cos", 10]
    ]
]
// wanted result: [-0.9589242746631385, -0.8390715290764524]
```

The error thrown is: `Expected array<number, 2> but found array<value, 2> instead.`

It seems the `literal` operator works with conventional arrays but cannot be used with expression arrays, as this example works when we remove the `sin` and `cos` functions:

```
"text-offset": [
    "literal", [5, 10]
]
// works but doesn't use Math operations, which are needed in my case
```

What is the correct syntax if I need to perform individual calculations on both the `x` and `y` part of the `text-offset` layout property? Thanks.

Comment: I think that at the moment it is impossible.

Comment: I believe it should be possible, as the Mapbox Style Specification says `text-offset` is supported for data-driven styling since version `0.35.0`. Source: [Mapbox Style Specification for text-offset](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-symbol-text-offset).

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6155

Comment: Thank you, it seems that for now we can only use data-driven styling for `text-offset` with GeoJSON sources.